# How to know the path file of image in picturebox?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a picturebox where I load a image at runtime using a OpenFileDialog, then I want to save the path/filename into a database. What I don't know is how to get the path/filename of the image?

I tried something like 
VB Code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    openFD.ShowDialog()

    If openFD.FileName > "" Then
        PictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFD.FileName
        PictureBox1.Imagelocation = label1.text

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

label1.text = PictureBox1.ImageLocation
or you can try to msgbox(PictureBox1.ImageLocation)